# PCI Device Missing After Reboot

Tags: devices, hardware, pci

I have a DVBSky T9580 PCI tuner card.

My problem is that after rebooting,, the device dissapears, `lspci` does not list it any more.

I tried rebooting with `reboot` command as well as `shutdown -r 0`. Only powering the PC off and on resolves the situation.

My questions are:

1. How can I isolate whether it is a hardware problem or Linux problem.
2. Is it possible to tell Linux to rescan the PCI bus for devices?

Comment: This doesn't answer your questions, but have you tried reseating the card?

Comment: If, from Linux's point of view, the card is sometimes detected during startup and sometimes not, depending on whether it was a cold boot or a warm boot, then it's a hardware problem: at the software level, startup after a cold boot and startup after a warm boot are the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem with my PCIe SSD, adding reboot=pci kernel parameter seems to solve the problem.